# Motion with friction

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to use DSolve to get an equation of motion with constant kinetic friction.

I used:

```
pmf[u_, g_, μ_] = DSolveValue[{x''[t] == -μ g, x'[0] == u, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
```

> $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 t u-g \mu  t^2\right)$

```
vmf[u_, g_, μ_] = Simplify[D[DSolveValue[{x''[t] == -μ g, x'[0] == u, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t], t]]
```

> $u-g \mu  t$

```
pmf[20, 9.8, 0.5]
```

> $\frac{1}{2} \left(40 t-4.9 t^2\right)$

```
vmf[20, 9.8, 0.5]
```

> $20-4.9 t$

Plotted it, and received the following:

```
Plot[pmf[20, 9.8, 0.5], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[vmf[20, 9.8, 0.5], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

However, it is unrealistic. I wanted to receive a practical equation where acceleration turns to zero when speed becomes zero.

When I tried to use Unit Step function on a depenpance of friction in the first derivative of the "pmf", it did not work.
Could you suggest some solution?

Comment: For friction models you need to have a force that is in the opposite direction of the velocity. This can be done by including the Sign of the velocity. This is now a non-linear equation and symbolic solutions from DSolve may not be possible. Numerical solutions are fine. I am also concerned that you have canceled the mass. Friction is proportional to the normal forces between surfaces (in the standard model). The normal force is perpendicular to the surface. So why does the mass cancel?

Comment: Your first plot is the position, not acceleration.

Comment: To Hugh: So it is better to use ndsolve?

Comment: To Feyre: I just wanted to check the correctness of the solution

Comment: Yes I suggest you use NDSolve. Also, my comment about directions may not be correct. Are you projecting the mass along a rough horizontal surface?

Comment: To Hugh: Yes, just for a simplest case

Comment: I wanted to make the simulation for an object with some aerodynamic properties and with friction together. However, I could not google sources about that. So, I started from the simplest thing that I thought.

Comment: This is a question in applied mechanics, and not a Mathematica question. It looks like you need to study up on your basic mechanics, first. The equation you are trying to solve certainly does not describe the physical problem you seem interested in.

Comment: Probably the missing ingredient here is [static friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction). But the question doesn't fully specify the actual problem to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is to project a mass along a rough horizontal plane. The normal force between the mass and the plane is then m g ( mass m and g acceleration due to gravity) the horizontal force in the standard friction model is then the coefficient of friction times m g. The friction force opposes the velocity so the sign of the velocity enters the equation. Here is an example

```
μ = 0.2;
g = 9.81;
u = 2;
tt = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -μ g Sign[x'[t]] , x'[0] == u, 
    x[0] == 0}, {x}, {t, 0, tt}];
```

Plotting displacement and velocity gives

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, tt}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Displacement time history"]
Plot[Evaluate[x'[t] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, tt}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Velocity time history"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope that helps.